# Why do we need to switch to an iframe to access elements inside it

Tags: java, iframe, selenium-webdriver

Html code which generates an `iframe`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="padding-top:10px;">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/url" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-size="large" data-show-screen-name="false">Follow @url</a>
        <script>!function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
            if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }
        }(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
    </div>                    
</body>
</html>
```

If I find this element by finding all 'a' tags in `iframe` then I get stale element reference exception.
If I switch to the `iframe` then I dont get the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium only interacts with elements in the current frame. Any element within a child frame cannot be interacted with until you switch into that frame. 
   It's consistent behavior with switching to another window or another tab in the same window because you actually have another HTML DOM, different than the original.

[The definition of an iframe from W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp): An iframe is used to display a web page within a web page.

**Iframe Syntax** 
The syntax for adding an iframe is:

```
<iframe src="URL"></iframe>
```

**Example**

```
<iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" width="200" height="200"></iframe>
```